# Using WPF Binding StringFormat with literals both for input and output

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a font point size chooser in WPF desktop app UI. I have previously used converter in such cases and it may well be the way to go here too.

However, there is StringFormat that I can use on binding which looks like simpler way (avoids creating a converter). It works fine for numeric value but it seems that I cannot add literals to the format like this: *StringFormat='{}{0:N} pt'*

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding SampleFontSize, StringFormat='{}{0:N} pt', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" IsEditable="True">
<ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>12</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem>14</ComboBoxItem>
```

Note the IsEditable=true

This will display "12,00 pt" in my locale but when I type in exactly the same value, it will trigger validation error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '12 pt' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=SampleFontSize; DataItem='AnalysisSettingsViewModel' (HashCode=47173034); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Shoudl I conclude that the StringFormat with literals works one way only, or am I using incorrect StringFormat? The **StringFormat={}{0:N}** works OK but not the **StringFormat={}{0:N} pt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "12 pt" is not a valid `double` value, the default converter won't be able to convert it back to a `double`. So yes, this indeed works one-way only.

You should use a custom converter that also knows how to convert the `string` to a `double`.

Comment: OK, this is the answer, even though not exactly the revelation I was seeking. The format is used for converting source value to string and string goes back to double through default converter. 
The reason why the StringFormat does not work both ways is probably in .NET itself - there is String.Format but there is no String.Parse because the formatted string cannot be converted back into _any_ type without loss. It would still work for base types.